# Using mutate to get number of ngrams

Tags: r, nlp, dplyr, stringr

I am using dplyr to parse a column containing sentences and calculating the number of ngrams for each one. Here is an example demonstrating the problem I am running into.

As you see, one expects ngram_cnt to be 3 and 4, but it results on a column having 3,3. The problem is that the code returns the number of ngrams for the first sentence, ignoring the rest. You may try to add further sentences, having the same effect. What am I doing wrong?

```
library(NLP)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

phrases <- c("this is the first", "and then comes the second")
df <- data.frame(phrase = phrases, id = c(1, 2))
df %>% mutate(ngram_cnt = length(ngrams(str_split(phrase, "\\s")[[1]], 2)))
```

If I say,

```
phrases <- c("this is the first", "and then comes the second",
             "and the third which is even longer")
df <- data.frame(phrase = phrases, id = c(1, 2, 3))
df %>% mutate(ngram_cnt = str_length(phrase))
```

then I get the expected results (namely, the length of each sentence).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because in

```
df %>% mutate(ngram_cnt = length(ngrams(str_split(phrase, "\\s")[[1]], 2)))
```

the `[[1]]` select only the split on the first sentence
that's the same as :

```
length(ngrams(str_split(phrases, "\\s")[[1]], 2))
# [1] 3
```

And after `mutate` puts `3` in every row

```
phrases <- c("this is the first", "and then comes the second")
df <- data.frame(phrase = phrases, id = c(1, 2))
library("dplyr")
```

You can apply your calculation by row with `rowwise` :

```
df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(ngram_cnt = length(ngrams(str_split(phrase, "\\s")[[1]], n = 2)))
# Source: local data frame [2 x 3]
# Groups: <by row>
# 
#                      phrase    id ngram_cnt
#                      (fctr) (dbl)     (int)
# 1         this is the first     1         3
# 2 and then comes the second     2         4
```

Or with a `group_by` if yours id are unique :

```
df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(ngram_cnt = length(ngrams(str_split(phrase, "\\s")[[1]], n = 2)))
# Source: local data frame [2 x 3]
# Groups: id [2]
# 
#                      phrase    id ngram_cnt
#                      (fctr) (dbl)     (int)
# 1         this is the first     1         3
# 2 and then comes the second     2         4
```

Or you can vectorize the function which calculate the length of ngrams :

```
length_ngrams <- function(x) {
  length(ngrams(str_split(x, "\\s")[[1]], n = 2))
}
length_ngrams <- Vectorize(length_ngrams)
df %>% mutate(ngram_cnt = length_ngrams(phrase))
#                      phrase id ngram_cnt
# 1         this is the first  1         3
# 2 and then comes the second  2         4
```